# Significantly lower accuracy and loss between TensorFlow versions (2.1.0 and 2.4.0)

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, keras, version

I was testing whether my DenseNet-121 implementation would work over GPU (RTX 2060) on Ubuntu, but when it ran successfully, I observed that loss and accuracy performed significantly worse than the performances set on CPU with a different computer.

I used the identical codes for the model and data preparation, an identical dataset, and identical training parameters.

The only difference was that the satisfactory macOS CPU version was running on TensorFlow version 2.1.0 whereas the Ubuntu GPU version was running on TensorFlow version 2.4.0.

To isolate the only observable difference, I went to the macOS version and updated TensorFlow to version 2.4.0, and now I am recording the same substantially worse results as on the other device.

**TensorFlow version 2.1.0 after 1 epoch:**

`593/593 [==============================] - 733s 1s/sample - loss: 0.3325 - accuracy: 0.8650`

**TensorFlow version 2.4.0 after 1 epoch:**

`38/38 [==============================] - 823s 21s/step - loss: 0.3732 - accuracy: 0.3920`

*Most noticeable here is the 0.473 difference in accuracy for an identical process between the new 2.4.0 and 2.1.0.

Would anyone know why this issue might be arising? Is the easiest solution to this just to go back to the last TensorFlow version with satisfactory results?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in one case you have 593 steps per epoch whereas in the other you have only 38 steps per epoch. If the batch sizes are the same in both cases then with only 38 steps you are not processing all your training samples. In fact you are only processing 3800/593=6.4 percent of the samples. This of course will lead to different results in accuracy.

Comment: I thought that might have been the issue as well, but it seems as if 2.1.0 lists in samples (individual data points), whereas 2.4.0 lists in batches. My batch size is 16. 593 samples / 16 batch size = 37.0625 steps  (hence the 38 steps in version 2.4.0).

Comment: I am running on 2.1 and it lists in steps of batches just as 2.4 does. I suspect you set the batch_size=1  in version 2.1 which then required 593 steps